# How can I avoid the nan values in mpfit.py?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, idl-programming-language

I used mpfit.py to get the some seasonal variation of data.
But I can't get the seasonal variation, because my observed data had some nan values. So I can't calculate them.

Do you know the skill to avoid or ignore nan values as NAN keyword of mpfitfun.pro of IDL?

When I used the IDL, I can ignore the nan values using NAN keyword.
Below is a example of IDL code.

result = MPFITFUN('MYGAUSS', t, d2009, 21.3756, start, /nan)

How can I ignore the nan values in python mpfit code?

If you know the method, Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mpfit, but if the NaNs are the problem then you could try to [drop them](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) then use mpfit with the rest of the data. Does it sound doable for you?

Comment: I understood your answer that push the NaNs values to end of array. If I right understood, I don't have to push them. Because my data is function of time series. Thank you for your answer alec_djinn :)

Comment: Pandas will do all for you, it can handle [time series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html) easily and drop the NaNs.